# Arcpy - Create an Historical Marker on an archiving enabled dataset in Oracle SDE

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, archiving

I am looking for a way to create an [Historical Marker](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/working-with-historical-markers.htm) programmatically with arcpy.

The archiving is enabled on a dataset in Oracle SDE.

I think, it's related with [arcpy Version Toolset](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/an-overview-of-the-versions-toolset.htm), but I can't find the documentation about this.

```
#this is an non-working attemp because CreateHistoricalMarker_management() method does not exists
import arcpy, datetime

my_dataset = "c:\\gis\\connection_file.sde\\an_archived_dataset\\a_feature_class"
marker_name = "A new dummy marker"
marker_datetime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

arcpy.CreateHistoricalMarker_management(my_dataset, marker_name, marker_datetime)

>>>AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CreateHistoricalMarker_management'
```

Comment: You're trying to call a tool/function that doesn't exist. I'm not an expert in this area, but a quick google search doesn't turn up anything I can see for arcpy and historical marker. My first guess is this stuff isn't available in arcpy. But since I dont have knowledge in this area, I'm not making this claim with certainty.

Comment: I know this method does not exist, but I know it's with the `CreateVersion_management()` arcpy method that it will work

Comment: sorry, I didnt fully read your comments in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer took from [Geonet Esri forum](https://community.esri.com/thread/191560-arcpy-create-an-historical-marker-on-an-archiving-enabled-dataset-in-oracle-sde):

To create a Historical Marker from Python, an option is using comTypes. Following  the next steps, you can create Historical Markers in a Enterprise Geodatabase from Python:

Environment: ArcGIS for Desktop 10.4.1 + Python 2.7

1. Install comtypes-0.6.2.win32.exe (attached)
2. Go to comtypes folder in
   `"C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\site-packages\comtypes"`, and delete the
   automation.pyc, automation.pyo, safearray.pyc, safearray.pyo files. 
   Edit the file automation.py and insert POINTER(BSTR):
   VT_BYREF|VT_BSTR, in the _ctype_to _vartype dictionary.
3. Delete all files in `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\site-packages\comtypes\gen`
4. Copy the file Snippets.py (attached), into `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib`
5. From Python Script you must to implement a function to create the Historical Marker.  (the example in the test.py file that can be found in [Geonet Esri forum](https://community.esri.com/thread/191560-arcpy-create-an-historical-marker-on-an-archiving-enabled-dataset-in-oracle-sde))